# Rails 4.1.1 Production: asset_path not working for fonts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to load glyphicons. In development it's working, since I don't have to precompile anything. But in production it doesn't load. The browser console says:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://production.site.com/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf"
```

Here's the line of my glyphicons.scss file:

```
@font-face{font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';src:url(asset_path('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot'));src:url(asset_path('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix')) format('embedded-opentype'),url(asset_path('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff')) format('woff'),url(asset_path('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf')) format('truetype'),url(asset_path('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular')) format('svg');}.glyphicon{position:relative;top:1px;display:inline-block;font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;line-height:1;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;}
```

My fonts folder is in app/assets:

```
app/
  assets/
  ├── fonts
  │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
  │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
  │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
  │   └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

And in my application.rb file I have this:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.svg *.eot *.woff *.ttf )
```

Isn't that all I have to do? I don't get where Rails is looking for the fonts at? How can I fix this?

==UPDATE==
From Mandeep's suggestions:

application.rb file:

```
# config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.svg *.eot *.woff *.ttf )
```

glyphicons.scss

```
@font-face{font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';src:font-url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');src:font-url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),font-url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),font-url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),font-url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');}.glyphicon{position:relative;top:1px;display:inline-block;font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;line-height:1;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;}
```

I pushed my code and redeployed, but it still doesn't work

Comment: which rails version are you using?

Comment: version 4.1.1 . should that affect anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Since you are using rails > 4 so you don't need to add fonts folder in assets as it's by default added in assets.*** Also you are using sass so you can use [**`font-url helper`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass). If you look at `docs` it says:

> When using the asset pipeline, paths to assets must be re-written and sass-rails provides -url and -path helpers (hyphenated in Sass, underscored in Ruby) for the following asset classes: image, font, video, audio, JavaScript and stylesheet.

So you can use it like this:

```
src: font-url('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
```

Comment: So the only change I have to make is in glyphicons.scss? Do I need to move the fonts folder anywhere?

Comment: @Edmund Yeah! You just need to change url part of glyphicons and you can even remove `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')` as it's already in assets path

Comment: I removed that line and changed everything to font-url and deployed again but it still doesn't work.. I'll update my question with the new code:

Comment: @Edmund you need to remove the asset part from url. It'll be `font-url('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');` not `font-url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');`

Comment: @Edmund same goes for other asset helpers too. When you use them you don't need to add `/assets/` part in url